# Some statements - true or false?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> I got an example exam in front of me and the first task has got
>   several short statements where you need to say "true" if true and
>   "false" if statement wrong (no need to say reason).
>
> a) The series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{k}$ is convergent for all $a \in
> \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$.
>
> b) The sequence $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$
>   if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ odd and $a_{n}=1$ if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ even
>   has only got one cluster point.
>
> c) $\inf \left \{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\geq0 \wedge e^{x}<1\right \}=0$

a) False. Let $a$ and or $k$ be $\infty$ then the series will diverge.

b) False because the sequence $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ has already got two cluster points (one at $1$ and the other at $0$).

c) True. First condition is clear that $0$ will be the smallest value. For the second condition, the only way getting smaller values than $1$ is by inserting negative values for $x$. Thus we will always have $\frac{1}{e^{x}}$ where $0$ is the infimum as well.

What do you think about this? Are my answers correct? Are my justifications correct?

Comment: For $a)$ your conclusion is correct but your reasoning is not.  You can't let "$a$ or $k$ be $\infty$."  $a$ is a real number, by assumption, and $k$ is your summation index.  You can, however, let $a=2$.  That's good enough.

Comment: For $b)$ I assume that $x_n=a_n$?  If so, then I agree with conclusion and reasoning.

Comment: For $c)$  Unless I am misreading, the set involved is empty.  There are no positive reals with exponentials less than $1$.  Somewhat counter intuitively, the infimum of an empty set is $\infty$.

Comment: Hi lulu tyvm. Not said in the task if $x_{n} = a_{n}$ so really no idea.

Comment: For a), can I also say "let $a$ and or $k$ be a big real number.."?

Comment: To your comment to c) but we are in $\mathbb{R}$ which also includes negative numbers. Putting these negative numbers into $e^{x}$, we get a negative exponent which is equivalent to $\frac{1}{e^{x}}$ or not?

Comment: And the infimum of this would be zero I think.

Comment: I took your wedge to mean the logical "and".  That is, you require both $x≥0$ AND $e^x<1$.  What did you mean by it?

Comment: You can't "let $k$ be" anything.  It's just a dummy variable.  Where possible, I'd try to be more specific than "a really big number".  That's why I proposed $a=2$ as a clear example.  Just a question of formality.

Comment: If it says $x\geq 0$ and if we got an "and" connection here, will it also have influences on the $x$ of $e^{x}$?

Comment: Yes!  You need both conditions to hold simultaneously.  As they are incompatible, you get $\emptyset$.

Comment: Oh nice that's very good to know, thanks so much :) So statements are: true, true, false. right?

Comment: False, True, False.  $a)$ is very much false...I just objected to your argument for it.

Comment: Oh yeah! But why is b true? :o

Comment: $b)$ is true for the reason you gave IF you assume that $x_n=a_n$.  If you don't make that assumption, then there is no way to answer the problem (as you have no information on $x_n$).

Comment: Oh now things get complicated for me, I think I will make an additional question just for this statement. Thanks a lot for your time by the way!!

Comment: Sorry, my error.  I meant to say that $b)$ is FALSE for the reason you gave (assuming that they intend $x_n=a_n$).  So then, yes.  The questions are all False.